# php foreach preg_match explode

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match, explode

I am creating a function that reads in a tab delimited text file and then stores the values in a two dimensional array.
The text file has a line of data then a line of just tabs (because it is exported from excel), I have chosen to use tabs over commas because there are commas in some of the values.

I open the file for reading, then use
$lines = file($filename);

to put each line of the file in the array as an element.

Then I use this foreach loop, and I would like to unset it if it is a line of all tabs, and explode it (to create the two dimensional array) if it has data.

This is my current code:

```
//loop through array to either explode into two dimentional array or to unset lines with only tabs(no letters)
foreach($lines as $index => $line)
{
    //work around so that it removes any lines with 2 tabs at the begining of the line, we know this because MRN and Patient Name is always included
    if (preg_match("/^\t{2}/", $line))
    {
        unset($lines[$index]);
        echo " unset";
    }
    else
    {
        $lines[$index] = explode("\t",$line);
        echo " explode";
    }

}
//use array_values() so that indexes are in standard form in array
$lines = array_values($lines);

echo "<pre>START";
print_r($lines);
echo "END</pre>";
```

This is the input:

```
Pam Administrator   2   gold

Charlotte   Office Organizer    3   purple
```

This is the output:

```
unset explode unset explode explode

STARTArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pam
            [1] => Administrator
            [2] => 2
            [3] => gold

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Charlotte
            [1] => Office Organizer
            [2] => 3
            [3] => purple

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

        )

)
END
```

My issue is that preg_match works if I do:

```
(preg_match("/^\t{2}/", $line))
```

but does not work if I do:

```
$tabcount=2;
(preg_match("/^\t{$tabcount}/", $line))
```

It just looks over it and returns false and does not unset the line.

Why does it do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: @Barmar is correct it does not look like you are using unset correctly. `foreach($lines as $line)` means $lines is the original array and $line is the value of that iteration in the foreach loop, so saying `unset($lines[$line]);` does not make sense because you are essentially saying `unset($lines["Pam Administrator 2 gold"]);`. That won't work because you have to use the key of that value to unset it. So like @Barmar said below you would need to `foreach($lines as $key => $value) ... unset($lines[$key]);` Are you ever seeing "unset" echoed out?

Comment: CSV provisions for entries with a comma by enclosing them with double quotes, so there's no reason you have to use tabs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$lines[$line]` is not the correct way to reference the element of the array. `$line` is the value, not the key.

```
foreach($lines as $index => $line)
{

    if (preg_match("/^\t{($columnammount-1)}\n/$", $line))
    {
        unset($lines[$index]);
        echo "unset";
    }
    else
    {
        $lines[$index] = explode("\t",$line);
        echo "explode";
    }

}
```

Change:

```
preg_match("/^\t{$tabcount}\n/", $line)
```

to:

```
preg_match("/^\t{{$tabcount}}\n/", $line)
```

The reason for this is that `{$variable}` is part of the syntax for variable interpolation -- the `{}` are needed for complex arrays, but they're also allowed for ordinary variables. So the whole expression, including the braces, is replaced by the variable value, resulting in a regexp `/^\t2/`. So you need to wrap another set of braces around it to get them to be retained for the regexp notation.

You could also use concatentation:

```
preg_match('/^\t{' . $tabcount . '}$/', $line)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, This is my current working code:<br/><pre>foreach($lines as $index => $line)
{
 //work around so that it removes any lines with 2 tabs at the begining of the line, we know this because MRN and Patient Name is always included
 if (preg_match("/^\t{2}/", $line))
 {
  unset($lines[$index]);
  echo " unset";
 }
 else
 {
  $lines[$index] = explode("\t",$line);
  echo " explode";
 }
 
}<code> The preg match works if I type in the actual number like this:if (preg_match("/^\t{2}/", $line)), but not if I put the variable in it like above, so I did a work around. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Long blocks of code are really hard to read in comments. If you want help with that, update your question.